# ACF submitting a form via ajax

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, advanced-custom-fields

is there a way ho to submit form created with `acf_form`via ajax so it doesn't redirect after submission?

This is the ACF form

```
acf_form_head();

acf_form(array(
    'post_id'       => 'new_post',
    'form_attributes' => array('id' => 'acf_form_new_map'),
    'new_post'      => array(
        'post_type'     => 'tome_map',
        'post_status'       => 'publish'
    ),
    'html_after_fields' => '<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="new_map" />',
    'form'  => true,
    'post_title' => true,
    'fields'      => array('field_54593ddcc6da5'),
    'submit_value'      => 'Save and insert new map',
    'return' => ''
));
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, assuming that you want to submit acf form on on button click without page refresh.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

     jQuery('form#acf_form_new_map:submit').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_data = {'action' : 'acf/validate_save_post'};
    jQuery('form#modalAjaxTrying :input').each(function(){
    form_data[jQuery(this).attr('name')] = jQuery(this).val()
    })

    form_data.action = 'save_my_data';
    jQuery.post(ajaxurl, form_data)
    .done(function(save_data){
    alert('Added successFully :');

    })

})
})
```